# How can I define a MacOS environment variable in install4j

Tags: macos, install4j

I have a problem with the Launcher in install4j. I need to define a library path in it, but the path may be different depending on the version of the installed library. Different users may have different paths. I need to be able to include a simple bash script, either in the launcher or in the installer, that will find the correct path, and include it in the launcher. Thank you.

The bash code would go like this:

```sh
MY_PATH=$($(ls -d /Library/somelibrary*/lib) |awk {'print $NF'})
```

to get the latest version of the library installed.

Answer (score 0):

GUI launchers on macOS are not based on a shell script, so you cannot add any shell script fragments to them.

You would have to load the library explicitly with `System.load()` instead of relying of the library path with `System.loadLibrary()`.